# Using cut() to make factor

Tags: r, cut

I am trying to make a factor variable out of a numeric variable in R. I would like to keep track of NA's and the new bins I am creating. Within the new bins, some numbers are of a valid range and some are not. I care about the bins themselves but want to create an "invalid" level that will house anything that does not fall in a designated range.

Here is an example:

```
library(reshape)

fac <- c(-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 100, NA)
fac <- cut(fac, c(-Inf, 1, 2, 3, Inf))
fac <- addNA(fac)
combine_factor(fac, 
           variable=order(levels(fac))[c(2,3,5)],
           other.label = "Invalid")
```

Which would give me some output that would have the levels I want to be intervals, NA, or invalid.

However, the trouble I am having is I do not want to code the variable using numbers because I have multiple different data sets and not all of them contain each level of the factor.

If I change the variable so that it does not contain any of a certain level of the factor:

```
fac <- c(-1, 1, 3, 4, 100, NA)
```

I keep getting the error:

> Error in factor(nvar[as.numeric(fac)], labels=c(levels(fac)[variable],
>   : invalid 'labels'; length 4 should be 1 or 3.

Output 1 (which works because I have no levels occurring 0 times):

```
[1] (1,2]   (1,2]   (2,3]   <NA>    Invalid Invalid Invalid
Levels: (1,2] (2,3] <NA> Invalid
```

Output 2 (where one level: (1,2] has 0 occurrences):

```
[1]   (2,3]   <NA>    Invalid Invalid Invalid 
Levels: (1,2] (2,3] <NA> Invalid
```

The second scenario is where I experience the error.

Is there any way I can get around this error?

Comment: What is the `combine_factor` function? Where is it from?

Comment: Its from the reshape package.

Comment: Please post your desired output for both tests.

Comment: Please check your desired output again. Both seem incorrect. Also, why would the order be as you've shown? See my answer for a possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about the `combine_factor` function, but it seems pretty easy to write your own....

Here's a basic example:

```
NewLevs <- function(fac, keep, others = "Invalid") {
  lf <- levels(fac)
  nl <- c(setNames(as.list(lf[keep]), lf[keep]),
    setNames(as.list(lf[-keep]), rep(others, length(lf)-length(keep))))
  levels(fac) <- nl
  fac
}
```

Here's some sample data:

```
fac1 <- c(-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 100, NA)
fac1 <- addNA(cut(fac1, c(-Inf, 1, 2, 3, Inf)))

fac2 <- c(-1, 1, 3, 4, 100, NA)
fac2 <- addNA(cut(fac2, c(-Inf, 1, 2, 3, Inf)))
```

Put the function to work:

```
fac1
# [1] (-Inf,1] (-Inf,1] (1,2]    (2,3]    (3, Inf] (3, Inf] <NA>    
# Levels: (-Inf,1] (1,2] (2,3] (3, Inf] <NA>
NewLevs(fac1, c(2, 3, 5))
# [1] Invalid Invalid (1,2]   (2,3]   Invalid Invalid <NA>   
# Levels: (1,2] (2,3] <NA> Invalid


fac2
# [1] (-Inf,1] (-Inf,1] (2,3]    (3, Inf] (3, Inf] <NA>    
# Levels: (-Inf,1] (1,2] (2,3] (3, Inf] <NA>
NewLevs(fac2, c(2, 3, 5))
# [1] Invalid Invalid (2,3]   Invalid Invalid <NA>   
# Levels: (1,2] (2,3] <NA> Invalid
```

The desired levels plus the label for unwanted levels can be changed:

```
NewLevs(fac2, c(1, 2, 3), "Wrong")
# [1] (-Inf,1] (-Inf,1] (2,3]    Wrong    Wrong    Wrong   
# Levels: (-Inf,1] (1,2] (2,3] Wrong
```